# How to force file download in the browser, nginx server

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I currently have 2 image locations and they may the formats (jpg,jpeg,png,gif)

```
i.domain.com/simage.jpg thumbnail
i.domain.com/image.jpg high quality
i.domain.com/o/image.jpg full resolution
```

Does anyone know how I can force image files in /o/ to download rather than render in the web browser?

Here's my conf file: http://pastebin.com/dP8kZMzx

```
#setup subdomain i.domain.com
server {
    server_name i.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/i..com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.com/test1/images;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #error_page 403 = /notfound.jpg;
    #error_page 500 = /notfound.jpg;

    location / {            
        #change this to a 404 img file .jpg
        try_files $uri $uri/ /notfound.jpg;

        rewrite  "/s([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /small/$1 break;
        rewrite  "/o/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /orig/$1 break;
        rewrite  "/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /medium/$1 break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried to figure out how to get this to work in a mixed Apache/Nginx settings for a long time. Ended up just excluding pdf from the list of file types served directly by Nginx and setting `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf` in .htaccess

Answer (score 33):

You just need to return HTTP header `Content-disposition`:

```
location ~* /orig/(.+\.jpg)$ {
    add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
}
```

Comment: This link works for me:http://210mike.com/force-file-download-nginx-apache/

location ~* (.*\.pdf) {
    types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
    default_type application/octet-stream;
}

Answer (score 22):

I have been trying to get this functionality into my own nginx server.

I have a folder on server that I would like to have open for anyone who knows the path.

To do that I added a /file/ location into my nginx config file.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location /file/ {
       alias /var/openStuff/file/;
       add_header Content-disposition "attachment";
   }
}
```

Any request to example.com/file/x will go to /var/openStuff/file and look for x and force the browser to download the file

This will also work if the path is /file/stuff/things.txt and will serve it from /var/openStuff/file/stuff/things.txt

Comment: Thanks you, perfect line put to end my 3 days search

Answer (score 5):

Below config works for me.

```
server {
    ...
    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/media;  
        types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
        default_type application/octet-stream;
    }
    ...
}
```

But the pdf file needs to ends with lowercase pdf for download to work. I still don't know the syntax to add both .pdf and .PDF to above config file. Any suggestion?
The answer is based on info from http://210mike.com/force-file-download-nginx-apache/

Answer (score 2):

A little mixing did the job for me. Forced to download a CRX file instead of installing or displaying.

```
## Download crx
location ~* \.crx$ {
    add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
}
```