# Download Button Opening Script

Tags: html, css, file, download

When my Clients download a rar from my website (ravens-hangar.tk) a big script of lines popping up. Need Help!? Thanks in Advance!

```css
.download {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #35424a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<td><img src="img/template7.png" alt=""><a href="repaints/ma.rar" download="ma'"><button type="button" class="download">Download</button></a></td>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGoFg.jpg

Comment: "big script of lines popping up" ?? please explain, we see nothing

Comment: check the image

Comment: this is oboviously the content of the rar file.

Comment: how can I fix it to download the file not to open the file?

Comment: Your server has to set the proper `Content-type` header in the HTTP response, so that your browser knows how to deal with the data.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download

Comment: by the way, why having button and link tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you remove the value of the attribute "download" the file is download normally or if you want another name write it with correct ending of your file like "another-ma.rar" not just "ma'" without file type. I think that button tag in a tag it's bad idea, maybe better give class="download" to anchor tag?  http://w3c.github.io/html/#the-a-element

I mean that if href="img.jpeg" it will open image in browser, but if you add download attr it will download image ;)

```css
.download {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #35424a;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<td><img src="img/template7.png" alt=""><a class="download" href="repaints/ma.rar" download>Download</a></td>
```

Comment: how will I change the size of the button?

Comment: padding in css or fixed size in px or em % but need add display: inline-block  or display: block; a tag is inline so need change it

Comment: Thanks Bro, for the big big help!

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in comments, your server must set the proper headers in the HTTP response. Something like this:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ma.rar"
```

To fix this, it depends on how your webpage and files are served. You have to read the documentation about 'How to properly serve your files'.

Comment: So I will add it on the html? or css?

Comment: This is neither about CSS nor about HTML. It is about your HTTP server, that is the component that sends the rar file (and the html webpages of your site certainly) to the browser.

Comment: If you do not deal with the backend, ask in your team. It could be Apache HTTP server, nginx, tomcat, node, i don't know! You must first figure out which server you use, then, you will be able to find some documentation about it, and learn how to properly save this kind of files.

Comment: can i put in htcacces?

Comment: with this? `<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: As you mention htaccess, i'll guess that you are using Apache HTTP Server. Your answer must be quite close, maybe the regex won't work though... Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056839/apache-directive-for-file-downloads

Comment: I've check and it is nginx @sjahan

Comment: If you're using nginx, you must be able to find some stuff around the web: check this out for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054354/how-to-force-file-download-in-the-browser-nginx-server