# Downloading array of image url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am wondering how to download all images , based on the URL in an array.
I have an array like such for example

```
['https://url/image1.jpg', 'https://url/image2.jpg']
```

I have introduced a piece of code below to create a link and simulate a click and download the item. But the problem is it always redirects to another page instead of downloading the file , and it also seems to happen only on the first image not both ?

```
selectedItems.forEach(function (item) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = item.url;
    link.download = item.description;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
 });
```

Does anyone have a better idea ?

Comment: You're clicking on a link. Why would it not open the link?

Comment: Just add `link.target = "_blank";` that would just open the images in new tab. Having the image download depends on server configuration (how to handle image types). Otherwise you can just implement blob download

Comment: @Goran.it That's not accurate. You can download an image in the browser without opening a new page/tab. See the question this is a "duplicate" off, linked above.

Comment: Fetch image as and download. https://jsfiddle.net/huxt0snd/

Comment: I am trying this now but it's going to AWS service, and even though I can open up the URL and see the image, when it goes through the GetFileBlob it errors on xhttp.onerror  @UmairKhan

Comment: @Culy, I didn't say It's not possible, I said it can be configured on server .. see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054354/how-to-force-file-download-in-the-browser-nginx-server
Also, I've noted at the end this can be done by using JS blob or other similar approaches coupled with link creation and clicking on it..